# ios Swift - API GoogleMaps - not conform protocol GSMAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, api, autocomplete, protocols

I'm trying to use API GoogleMaps in an ios app to make an auto-completion, but I can't get my hand on the problem, I search for it but it seems I'm the only one to have it.

> MyViewController doesn't conform to protocol GSMAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func onLaunchClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        acController.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(acController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension MyViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

    func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController!, didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace!) {
        // The user has selected a place.
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController!, didAutocompleteWithError error: NSError!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func wasCancelled(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

It seems like I don't have all the protocol required, but can't get my hand on it.

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController!, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: NSError!) {

}
```

Comment: No problem.  Have a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_autocomplete_view_controller_delegate-p?hl=en