# ViewController does not conform to protocol GMSAutoCompleteViewControllerDelegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am getting the error: 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'GMSAutoCompleteViewControllerDelegate' in the following code.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate, GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

...

@IBAction func autocompleteClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        let autoCompletController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autoCompletController.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(autoCompletController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //Handle user's selection
    func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController!, didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace!) {
        //let placeName = place.name
        //let placeAddress = place.formattedAddress
        //let placeAttributions = place.attributions
        let placeCoordinate = place.coordinate
        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: placeCoordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
    }

    func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController!, didAutocompleteWithError error: NSError!) {
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.description)
    }

    func wasCancelled(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What would the fix be? Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_autocomplete_view_controller_delegate-p), and made sure you've implemented the required functions?

Comment: Yes I got this code from the google docs and double checked with the api that I had all the required functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios Swift - API GoogleMaps - not conform protocol GSMAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676576/ios-swift-api-googlemaps-not-conform-protocol-gsmautocompleteviewcontrollerd)

Comment: The google developer guide seems to be missing the necessary 'didFailAutocompleteWithError'. That's what was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you've mistyped one of the required functions. The `didAutoCompleteWithError`

```
func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController!, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: NSError!) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: ", error.description)
}
```

---

**Edit:**
*Information regarding the GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate protocol reference given in the GoogleDevelopers docs.*

One of the examples google provide in their docs is an erroneous representation of the GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate. It seems that the example is a pure translation from the Objective-C equivalent and therefore giving a wrong depiction of the required delegate functions.

Compare the [example](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete), with the actual docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_autocomplete_view_controller_delegate-p). Take notice
   to the `didAutocompleteWithError` in the example and the
   `didFailAutocompleteWithError` in the protocol reference.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The developers guide indicate the 'didAutoCompleteWithError' however the 'didFailAutocompleteWithError' is in fact the necessary call

Answer (score 4):

I just received this error in Swift 3 and changing it to the following worked for me:

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Swift.Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Big up, saved me :)

Answer (score -1):

You're probably missing a required function in the `GMSMapViewDelegate` protocol.  Ctrl + click into `GMSMapViewDelegate` and look at the functions listed: have you implemented all the functions that are not listed as `@optional`?  If you haven't, swift will not compile.